# Finding past events in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of measurements done semi-periodically - it means that they should be done in an interval, however sometimes there will be NA and measurement will be restarted.

On another list, I have information about events.

For each measurement, I would like to know the date of last event in the past. How can I do it in R, preferably using dplyr?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

measurements <- tibble(timestamp = seq(ymd('2017-01-01'), 
                                       ymd('2017-01-20'), 
                                       by = "2 days"),
                       data = runif(10))

events <- tibble(timestamp = ymd('2017-01-04', '2017-01-12'), 
                 type = 'Start')

expected = ymd(NA, NA, '2017-01-04', '2017-01-04', 
               '2017-01-04', '2017-01-04', 
               '2017-01-12', '2017-01-12',
               '2017-01-12', '2017-01-12')

measurements %>% mutate(distance = expected)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
    timestamp       data   distance
       <date>      <dbl>     <date>

 1 2017-01-01 0.01037106         NA
 2 2017-01-03 0.50183512         NA
 3 2017-01-05 0.80695523 2017-01-04
 4 2017-01-07 0.98605880 2017-01-04
 5 2017-01-09 0.78591144 2017-01-04
 6 2017-01-11 0.02296494 2017-01-04
 7 2017-01-13 0.94335407 2017-01-12
 8 2017-01-15 0.10540759 2017-01-12
 9 2017-01-17 0.27344290 2017-01-12
10 2017-01-19 0.09080328 2017-01-12
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean with "the last". Presuming you want 2017-1-1 for distance 2017-01-04, then this will work: `measurements %>% mutate(distance = expected) -> d; d %>% group_by(distance) %>% summarise(min(timestamp))`.

Comment: Actually ```expected``` is the o/p OP wants. The condition is ```measurements$timestamp``` must be compared with ```events$timestamp```  and the recent / last date must be applied to distance.

Comment: I just want to calculate variable "expected" instead of typing it.

Comment: At a first glance, this looks like a case for a rolling join, which is currently [not supported by `dplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240). It should be straightforward with `data.table` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to `expand` the data, then `left_join` with the other dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
events %>% 
    transmute(timestamp, distance = timestamp) %>%
    right_join(., expand( measurements, timestamp = seq(first(timestamp),
                        last(timestamp), by = "day"))) %>%
    fill(distance) %>% 
    left_join(measurements, ., by = 'timestamp')
 # A tibble: 10 x 3
 #   timestamp      data   distance
 #      <date>     <dbl>     <date>
 #1 2017-01-01 0.6299731         NA
 #2 2017-01-03 0.1838285         NA
 #3 2017-01-05 0.8636441 2017-01-04
 #4 2017-01-07 0.7465680 2017-01-04
 #5 2017-01-09 0.6682846 2017-01-04
 #6 2017-01-11 0.6180179 2017-01-04
 #7 2017-01-13 0.3722381 2017-01-12
 #8 2017-01-15 0.5298357 2017-01-12
 #9 2017-01-17 0.8746823 2017-01-12
 #102017-01-19 0.5817501 2017-01-12
```

---

Or another option is `data.table` by specifying the `roll`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(measurements)[as.data.table(events)[, distance := timestamp
    ], distance := distance , on = 'timestamp', roll = -Inf
     ][, distance := na.locf(distance, na.rm = FALSE)]
measurements
#     timestamp      data   distance
# 1: 2017-01-01 0.2387260       <NA>
# 2: 2017-01-03 0.9623589       <NA>
# 3: 2017-01-05 0.6013657 2017-01-04
# 4: 2017-01-07 0.5150297 2017-01-04
# 5: 2017-01-09 0.4025733 2017-01-04
# 6: 2017-01-11 0.8802465 2017-01-04
# 7: 2017-01-13 0.3640919 2017-01-12
# 8: 2017-01-15 0.2882393 2017-01-12
# 9: 2017-01-17 0.1706452 2017-01-12
#10: 2017-01-19 0.1721717 2017-01-12
```

NOTE: As the `seed` was not set, if we create the 'measurement' dataset again, the values for 'data' (`rnorm`) will be different

Or as @Henrik mentioned if we don't want to change the 'measurements' dataset, we can do

```
setDT(events)[setDT(measurements), .(timestamp, data, x.timestamp),
             on = "timestamp", roll = Inf]
```

Comment: Or `setDT(events)[setDT(measurements), .(timestamp, data, x.timestamp), on = "timestamp", roll = Inf]`